# I am trying to get jQzoom to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting  a type error undefined in my javascript when I inspect it in firebug. I am using wordpress and am using query. I have enqued my scripts and they show up when I inspect the page. when i look at the call for the Jqzoom i get the following error.

LINK TO SITE

http://www.goodmorningmoon.ca/shop/deer/
pass: springy88

```
jquery TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function(evaluating '$(window)')
```

javascript call to jqzoom

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.MYCLASS').jqzoom();  
});
```

html markup

```
<a href="http://img.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2008/05_03/bigcowBNS_468x341.jpg" class="MYCLASS" title="MYTITLE"> 
                        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php get_the_title(get_field('purchaseImage1')) ?>" title="IMAGE TITLE"/>
                    </a>
```

Comment: could you post your html markup is your plugin code inserted after the jQuery libary and before your code ?

Comment: the jquery library is before the jqzoom library and then my code is after. I can link to live site in a second.

Comment: Do you use any additional plugins or libraries on this page? Are they before or after this code?

Comment: @shersen the only plugin I am using is the advanced custom fields plugin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed to wrap my document in jQuery(document).ready

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.MYCLASS').jqzoom(); 
});
```